# How to show additional information in Jenkins with JUnit?

Tags: xml, jenkins, junit

I implemented Google unit test and created a test report named `output.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="13" failures="2" disabled="0" errors="0" timestamp="2023-04-10T10:41:58" time="0.027" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="MultiplyMatrixParallelTest" tests="5" failures="2" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.007">
    <testcase name="STD1" status="run" time="0.005" classname="MultiplyMatrixParallelTest">
      <failure message="N:\Perforce\WS_UnitTestRunner\depot\VectorOperationsLib\VectorOperationsLib_UnitTest.cpp:12&#x0A;Value of: std::equal(ResultMat, ResultMat + 1, expectedOutput)&#x0A;  Actual: false&#x0A;Expected: true" type=""><![CDATA[N:\Perforce\WS_UnitTestRunner\depot\VectorOperationsLib\VectorOperationsLib_UnitTest.cpp:1 Value of: std::equal(ResultMat, ResultMat + 1, expectedOutput)
      Actual: false
      Expected: true]]></failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="STD2" status="run" time="0" classname="MultiplyMatrixParallelTest" />
      <failure message="N:\Perforce\WS_UnitTestRunner\depot\VectorOperationsLib\VectorOperationsLib_UnitTest.cpp:46&#x0A;Value of: std::equal(ResultMat, ResultMat + 1, expectedOutput)&#x0A;  Actual: false&#x0A;Expected: true" type=""><![CDATA[N:\Perforce\WS_UnitTestRunner\depot\VectorOperationsLib\VectorOperationsLib_UnitTest.cpp:4 Value of: std::equal(ResultMat, ResultMat + 1, expectedOutput)
      Actual: false
      Expected: true]]></failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="STD3" status="run" time="0" classname="MultiplyMatrixParallelTest" />
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="TanhTest" tests="3" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.005">
    <testcase name="STD1" status="run" time="0" classname="TanhTest" />
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="PrintInfo" tests="1" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.008">
    <testcase name="ConfigInfo" status="run" time="0.006" classname="PrintInfo">
<properties>
<property name="Kernel_Type" value="winnt"/>
<property name="Kernel_Version" value="10.0.19045"/>
<property name="Machine_Host_Name" value="XPS15-Falcon"/>
<property name="Product_Info" value="Windows 10 Version 2009"/>
<property name="User_Name " value="Falcon"/>
<property name="Build_Environment_Info " value="MSVS 2019, Unicode, Release"/>
</properties>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I want to show the content of this `.xml` file into Jenkins, **especially the content in tag** `properties` (Kernel_Type, Kernel_Version, Machine_Host_Name and so on) . I configured JUnit like this.

[image]

But when I build it in Jenkins, I do not see the content of tag `properties`

[image]

How to show content in tag `properties` in Jenkins?